# How can I keep a disc spinning in the DVD ROM drive?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I just want to keep the DVD spinning in the DVD ROM drive once the disc is inserted.

My only purpose is to reduce the disc spin up time when the user finally wishes to play the DVD at some later point in time.

Users can choose whether s/he wants to prevent the disc from spinning down.

So, the question really is how can I change the spindown timeout for DVD ROM drive to **never**?

Comment: This sounds like a horrible idea - esp. on a laptop.  I think we can all handle 2 seconds to start a DVD.

Comment: Please don't do that. DVD drives may be quite noisy and having to listen to that just to potentially speed up playback that may or may not happen would be a disaster if you ask me.

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: **Please** don't vote to migrate this to Super User.

Comment: Closed and reopened this question (to prevent migration). My understanding is that the OP wants to achieve their goal programmatically, so this is a valid question. I'm pretty sure it doesn't belong on Super User, and why anyone wanted to migrate this to Server Fault is beyond me.

Comment: @balpha: That sounds reasonable. Reopening (again).

Comment: Nooo...Think of all the little electrons that will have to die just to save your users a few seconds :-(

Comment: As rightly said balpha, I'm trying to do this programmatically. I do understand all the concerns raised by members but many of the endusers find the delay intolerable. And we can ofcourse reduce the delay by keeping the disc spinning.

Comment: @scunliffe - esp. on a laptop.. why? Also, the spin up time is more than a couple of seconds, and the difference when playing a disc when it is sitting idle in the tray, and when it is playing from a spun up disc is drastic.

Comment: @Brian - Didn't get you actually and since your comment has been "liked" five times, I guess I missing something very obvious. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This will also unnecessarily increase wear on the drive motor.

Comment: @ShellShock - Drive motors are motors and they are supposed to spin. And I agree with your wear and tear issue. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: @Trainee4Life - because nothing kills battery life on a laptop better than spinning physical parts (e.g. a CD/DVD player). As for the time, I think its fine. I would ***much*** rather wait 2,3,..5 seconds for a disc to spin up than have it constantly spinning just in case I *may* want it later on.  It will waste power, add unnecessary wear on the drive.  Similarly I could leave my car running outside while I'm at work so that when I go out it is ready to go - but I wouldn't as it is wasteful, noisy, etc. If spin up time is the issue, put in on a USB Key or the HD instead.

Comment: @scunlife - you would leave your car running if you are trying to pull off a heist.. *humour intended*. similar situation here.. can someone provide me with an answer..

Comment: I am shocked at the number of people responding with questions and comments to the effect of "WHY OH WHY would you want to do that?!  I don't like laptop battery drain or drive noise... waa-waa-waaa!!!"  The question wasn't "Is ___ good idea?"  Trainee4Life has a legitimate question.  In fact, I arrived here by searching "prevent DVD drive spinning down" because that is exactly what I want to do.  Why?  Maybe I have a fetish for drive spin.  Who cares!  Answer the question or don't.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can keep reading from it at some interval.

But then if the user wants to eject the disk?
Or do some other operation that would need a "full lock" on the DVD rom?
Continuously reading the disk would make some operations more difficult and may increase frustration.

When the user decides to play a DVD, she knows the (little) initial delay before playing. I don't think you are going to gain anything great by minimizing this time.

DVD is pretty well known technology and when someone uses it they know what to expect.

And if someone is unhappy with the initial start time, for them there are other technologies.

Comment: If the user wants to eject the disk, then I'll allow them to eject. "Full lock" operations.. I don't mind.. I'll give up on reading the disk. Is reading from the disc the only choice only implementing this feature? And I don't want to read the disc if its already spinning. As earlier commented, "the difference when playing a disc when it is sitting idle in the tray, and when it is playing from a spun up disc is drastic". So why not provide our endusers with this feature?

Comment: Assuming the solulution we take is reading from the disk at a interval, then how do you know when the user wants to eject the disk, or full lock operations, how would your program _know_ that the user wants to do something like this? Though this may definitely be possible programatically (closely with the OS), but i don't think it is worth the hassle. And also like Brian Rasmussen told in the comments, DVDs can be pretty noisy also.

Comment: That said, it is pretty much up to you to decide (keeping in mind your purpose and target audience). I prefer we can agree to disagree, and wait for an answer that would give the actual answer: how to do what you want :-)

Comment: This depends on many factors, such as filesystem cache: if the bit you want to read is cached, the disk won't be needed.  It does seem like a good naive solution (that is, without directly accessing OS-details to do what you really want: change the spindown timeout).

Comment: @Roger - So the question really boils down to how can I change the DVDROM drive spindown timeout to never. (Updated my question) Any ideas on how to go about doing it?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could seek random bits of file from the disk every coupe of seconds?

Comment: Any clever ideas on how to go about doing that? I don't want to "unnecessarily" read the disc if its spinning, or being used by other apps.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of keeping the drive spinning, is there any chance you could buffer a couple seconds worth so that you have the data ready in memory whilst the drive spins up?

Comment: Not possible with the current infrastructure in place. I don't control from "where" the dvd is played - bufferring few seconds would mean that dvd starts playing *from* the buffer initially till the drive spins up and then it smoothly reads *from* the disc.

Comment: @Trainee4Life: You could always start reading from the DVD in a seperate thread and use that to fill the buffer. Maybe better would be to create your own Stream and that would handle the buffer transparently for the rest of the code, switching between memory and DVD as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Windows has a "DVD Drive Spin Down Timeout" setting in the registry that you could modify:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sounds perfect, but for some reason, it’s allegedly only available on laptop computers, and I can’t find it in my Windows 7 desktop computer registry.

Answer (score 2):

There are SCSI device parameter values which can be set on the device known as the "Idle Condition Timer" and "Standby Condition Timer".

If you set these to higher than their defaults, or to be ignored completely, then the drive will keep on spinning!

See "[Power Condition mode page (1Ah)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170219015421fw_/http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/scsi/100293068a.pdf#page=305)"

One command line util that can do this is sdparm.

Comment: Found this via https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454449/optical-drive-power-settings-wait-longer-before-spinning-down/454466#comment825867_454449 .

Answer (score 0):

You can read disk, then her will be keep spinning in your drive.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this programmatically depends on the OP's OS. That being said I believe its safe to say that in MS environments, a simple script to activate/deactivate the device (on a driver level) can accomplish this. On Linux/Unix-based platforms a script that kills/runs the CD-DVD ROM Daemon would similarly suffice. Several factors would determine how the front end would look- dependant on the OP's unstated requirements, i.e. aesthetic, programming language of choice, etc. This could be written up as an app or it could be a simple batch file, it all depends on how elegant a solution the OP requires. This is a manual solution though (you would have to click on it everytime), but one could link the DVD ROM autorun function to the script.